# How to distribute data from one ms sql table into another ms sql database

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I am using MS SQL Server 2014.
I have a "main" server that contains a database which contains a table with data. This table receives new data around every second. Per day it is currently around 500'000 new rows. As the data only stay for some days in this table, the table contains a maximum of 1'500'000 rows.

I have a "mandate" server that contains the same database (structure) which contains the same table (structure).

I want to write (distribute) the new data arrived from my "main" server table to my "mandate" server table (also around every second). Updates or deletes do not need to be distributed (only the new arrived rows of the last second(s)).
I want to keep the resources used on my "main" server for the distribution as low as possible. Currently, there is only one "mandate" server, however, in the future there might be more of them (with the same needs).

Is replication the best thing to use here (esp. regrading the resources (as low as possible on the "main" server but on the burden of the "mandate" server(s)) and frequency (very second)?
Alternatively, a self-made SQL job on the "mandate" server to pull the data from the "main" server is also possible but I think if there are multiple "mandate" servers frequently pulling data from the "main" server table it might use to many resources.

What is the best way to distribute the data in my case here?